# How to get FusionIO card to be recognized by VMware ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I am working on a new IBM Bladecenter setup with a few blades that have the 320GB FusionIO cards. I have high hopes that they will be super speedy for a few VMs running Oracle or some sort of database.

My question is this: I want to install 3 vms on the SSDs however the SSDs are not shown when I attempt to create a new VM, only the mirrored drive that comes with the blade. I was able to add the devices as passthrough devices. However, this only allows the device to be used by one VM. This seems silly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Did you install the ESX drivers available from http://support.fusionio.com/ ?  Without the ESX drivers, they won't be visible as storage devices in vSphere manager, only as pass-thru devices.

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention which version of ESXi you're using but they're only supported on 4.0U1 onwards. What happens in the vsclient when you select configuration/storage or storage adapters, do they not show up as available LUNs at all? presumably you've done add-storage from configuration/storage to create the datastores?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that info. It's ESXi 4.1 installed in the last few weeks. I looked through various configuration screens and was unable to see the devices show up at all. The only time I see it is in the passthrough device configuration.